# Partial hydrolysis of XeF6

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, hydrolysis

What are the products of partial hydrolysis of $\ce{XeF_6}$?
Is $\ce{XeOF_4}$ formed or $\ce{XeO_2F_2}$ is formed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both can be formed. It depends on the amount of water added: 
\begin{align}
&&\ce{XeF6 + H2O  &->  XeOF4 + 2HF}\\
&\text{or}&
\ce{XeF6 + 2H2O &-> XeO2F2 + 4HF}\\
&\text{or even}&
\ce{XeF6 + 3H2O &-> XeO3 + 6HF}
\end{align}

Comment: @Martin - マーチン Why Xenic acid is not produced ?